# Error publishing on appstore - Storyboard file 'MainStoryboard_iPad~ipad.storyboardc' was not found

Tags: ipad, publish

I have the error: "ERROR ITMS-90029: "Storyboard file 'Main_iPad~ipad.storyboardc' was not found. Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename.", When I try to submit to the app store from xcode.

I've tried all solutions that I found posted in stackoverflow with no luck.

I've removed the value for the key Main storyboard file base name in the project's info.plist file. and also I've delete the entry since it's no design for ipad, but it did not work.

I generated the IPA file and try to submit with aplication loader but produces the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I resolved it by doing this:

- Remove Main_iPad~ipad.storyboardc from info.plist (you already did this)
- Remove your Apple ID in account Xcode->Preferences->Accounts
- Close and reopen Xcode.
- Add your Apple ID again (If you were using a @me account, change it for @icloud).
- Clean, build, archive.
- Upload to iTunes from Xcode or export the IPA and then use Application loader. In my case it worked unchecking the bottom left corner option ¨send bit code".